# PNPPowershell Add-PNPListItem date columns fail when using -Batch

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, date-time

Trying to take a csv file and import it into an existing SharePoint list. I started with [this sample](https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/spo-import-csv-data-to-existing-sharepoint-list/README.html?tabs=pnpps) and have made some modifications for our specific case.

The example uses `New-PnPBatch` and `Invoke-PnPBatch` to batch the `Add-PnPListItem` cmdlets and should save on REST calls and increase the speed of our script. But when run the script with the batch feature I get errors on all of our date fields like this:

```
There was an exception while writing field reviewdate. Verify you're using the correct InternalName value for the field you want to write to.
```

There are three date fields in the list and I've checked the internal names and they are all correct. Additionally if I remove the -Batch switch (or comment it out like this)

```
Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values $values #-Batch $batch
```

Then the items are added successfully to the list. **Edit** Also if I remove the date columns from the csv I can use the batch feature just fine. So I'm pretty sure it has something specific to do with date columns.

I see from [this documentation](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/batching.html) that `Add-PnPListItem` is supported for batching and no mention of issue with date columns are included.

Anybody else know what is going on and why I can't use `-Batch` when adding list items that have dates?

Comment: It might be worth adding an issue to the PnP PowerShell GitHub repo, given that it works without the batch switch. Looks like a bug or at least a documentation issue: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues also are you using the latest version of PnP?

Comment: Thanks. I am using PNP.PowerShell 1.10 and PowerShell 7.2.3. I don't know how to open an issue, but I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `Add-PnPListItem` deals with date columns differently between Batch and Non-Batch mode.

My code was round-tripping some dates exported to CSV from a list and were in a format like **4/13/2021 12:00:00 AM**. This worked fine when adding items in non-batch mode. But batch mode is expecting dates in this format **2021-04-13 00:00:00**.

I changed up the code a bit

```
$date =[datetime]::parseexact($csvDate,'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', $null)
$val = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

And then used the $val for the value sent. This value works in both batch and non-batch.

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution, please mark your answer as the accepted answer to the question.